# C# and how to use "System.Timers"

Tags: c#, timer

I recently started to use C# and I wanted to use timers.

I read Windows help about how to declare and define a Timer. 
What I don't understand is why I need the `Console.ReadLine();` line to start the timer. 
([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) to the example)

```
// Firstly, create a timer object for 5 seconds interval 
timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 5000;

// Set elapsed event for the timer. This occurs when the interval elapses −
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.AutoReset = false;
// Now start the timer.
timer.Enabled = true;

Console.ReadLine(); // <------- !!!
```

What I want to do but I don't achieve is to start the timer as soon as it is declared. I dont want to write `Console.ReadLine();` because I may not need a console.

Example: If i develop a timer class and I call it from an other class, how can I check the timer has been completed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `Console.ReadLine` is not there to start the timer but to stop the program from exiting.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` prevent the application from exiting before the timer expires.

Comment: Is your app a console application? A WPF application? Something else? What do you need a timer for in the first place? Judging by your "Example" I feel like a timer might not be the best thing to use here...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Timer, than wait for time is elapsed which executes the OnTimedEvent, that is how you can check if it already elapsed.

```
    // Create a timer with a two second interval.
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
```

The OnTimedEvent should look like this:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                      e.SignalTime);
}
```

If you need to Stop the timer you should call:

```
   timer.Stop();
   timer.Dispose();
```

You need Console.ReadLine(); just for not exiting the main method and the whole program. If you're developing something else like MVC or WPF, you don't need it.